# How to punctuate math fractions?

Tags: punctuation, mathematics, fractions

I was doing the [Writing and interpreting decimals](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/arithmetic/decimals/decimal_place_value/e/writing-and-interpreting-decimals) exercise on [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) and was asked the following question:

> What is nine and three hundred two thousandths in numerical form?

I read it as "What is nine and three hundred... two thousandths", i.e. 9 and 300/2000 instead of "What is nine and three hundred two... thousandths", i.e. 9 and 302/1000.

Should there be a punctuation difference between the two?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (though it's possible I am), it should be *three-hundred-two thousandths* for 302/1000 and *three-hundred two thousandths* (*two-thousandths*?) for 300/2000. On the other hand,

Comment: _Three hundred two thousandths_ is ambiguous, as you note. I'd use _three hundred over two thousand_ and either _three hundred two one thousandths_ or _three hundred two over a_ (or: _one_) _thousand_.

Or I'd reduce it to lowest terms by dividing out common factors. `:-)`

Comment: In BrE, it becomes clearer: 'nine and three hundred and two thousandths' (=9.302). But 'three hundred and two and three hundred and two thousandths' is getting a little more opaque.

Answer (score 3):

Math has its own idioms that are a subset of "normal" English.  I can see where there might be some confusion to someone unfamiliar with those idioms, but one would never read or write "300/2000" as "three hundred ... two thousandths".   It would be "300 over 2000" or "300 out of 2000" or possibly reduced to "3 out of 20".

So I would argue it is mathematically unambiguous as written and additional punctuation is unwarranted.

Adding hyphens between the words as Kevin suggested in the comment ("three-hundred-two thousandths) *might* avoid some confusion, but is inconsistent with the typical [grammar rules](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/images/ch07_tab01.pdf) of hyphenating numbers.

Comment: *"one would never read or write '300/2000' as 'three hundred ... two thousandths'"*. Do you have a source for this assertion?