# Why is “one one-thousandths of a second” plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, fractions

The other day I came across this page and found a phrase strange to me.

[The Britannica Dictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/thousandths)

> a/one thousandth of a second
> = one one-thousandths of a second [= <sup>1</sup>/<sub>1000</sub> second]

The plural "s" confused me so much.
Then, I checked the [*hundred*](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/hundred) entry of the same site.

> one hundredth of a second
> = one one-hundredth of a second [= <sup>1</sup>/<sub>100</sub> second]

There is no plural "s" with "hundredth"! Now I'm relieved. The writer must have made a mistake.
"One one-thousandth of a second" (without s) should be right.

But I checked a news site to make sure.

> - But Montgomery is the world record with a time of 9.78 seconds, **one one-hundredths of a second** faster than Greene's best time. (New York Post)
> - In one of the most thrilling 100-meter finals in Olympic history,
>   Gatlin won gold by **one one-hundredths of a second**. (New York Post)
> - She finished fourth in the trials with a time of 11.11, just one
>   **one-hundredths of a second** behind third-place finisher Lauryn
>   Williams. (New York Post)

Now I'm totally confused again.
Somebody help me (an English teacher from Tokyo).
Both are OK?
Why can you make it plural?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to punctuate math fractions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132244/how-to-punctuate-math-fractions)

Comment: I don't see that the linked question addresses this. That relates to how the numerator is constructed, but here the numerator can't reasonably be read as anything other than one, but the denominator is still given in the plural

Comment: It's an awkward construction to start with, possibly influenced by some of the points raised at the linked question. This awkwardness may lead to a bit of confusion in writing the sports news quotes, but the Brittanica example sentence should have been properly checked. I can't see a way for it to be correct. I have wondered in the past how well the examples in online dictionaries are curated, as some are a little odd, but this goes further. Even without the error (and the mismatch - it reads as "singular=plural") it's neither a good example nor a good definition, but tries to be both

Comment: I agree with you-  It shouldn’t be plural there.

Comment: It looks odd, but the units are one thousandths of a second.

Comment: @Jim I agree, "three one-thousandths of a second" would be correct since there are more than one of the units of time, however "one three-thousandths of a second" would be incorrect as there is only one of the units of time. It's a typo, even dictionaries aren't immune to typographical errors.

Comment: @WeatherVane I disagree, the unit is one-thousandth of a second, it's only plural if there are more than one of them. Why should a thousandth be any different linguistically from a quarter, a tenth, a ninety-second, a hundred-and-fiftieth or any other fractional unit. It's a typo.

Comment: @BoldBen the dictionary's examples are one thousandth of a second, and one one thousandths of a second. So the question "How many one thousandths of a second?" could be answered "One one thousandths of a second." Perhaps this is the difference between casual speech and a formal unit. "We were going at one mile per hour" and "the velocity was one miles/hour".

Comment: This is a pity, as Britannica Dictionary does, unlike many other dictionaries, point out the variants available. But it should read << a/one thousandth of a second = one one-thousandth of a second [= 1/1000 second] >>. Note that while 'one third of a second' is fine, 'one one-third of a second' is unacceptable. I'd say 'one one-hundredth' is where the prefixed _one_ becomes allowable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The *one one-ᴏʀᴅɪɴᴀʟ of an X* is almost always better expressed by changing the reduplicative "one one-" bit to read simply "a/an" as demonstrated by *less than (a) half a second, less than a third of a second, less than a fifth of a second, less than an eighth of a second, less than a tenth of a second, less than a twelfth of a second, less than a hundredth of a second, less than a thousandth of a second, less than a millionth of a second*. I trust you find rewriting any of those with *one one-* results in a clumsy and potentially confusing form ranging from awkward to awful.

Comment: @tchrist In most contexts, yes. But there are a raw 450 000 Google hits for "one one-thousandth" and 200 000 for "one one-hundredth", including dictionary examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [Maybe there are, maybe there aren't](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+one+hundredth+of%2Cone+one+thousandth+of%2Ca+hundredth+of%2Ca+thousandth+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20one%20hundredth%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20one%20thousandth%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hundredth%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20thousandth%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cone%20one%20hundredth%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20one%20thousandth%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hundredth%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20thousandth%20of%3B%2Cc0). Hmmmm.

Comment: Thank you everyone. The dictionary was wrong and New York Post made mistakes. Is that the conclusion?

Comment: I believe the conclusion is correct. The question thus deals with published mistakes rather than usage, so I am voting to close it.

Comment: I believe the conclusion is correct. The question thus deals with published mistakes rather than usage, so I am voting to close it.

Comment: I wrote an e-mail to the Britannica dictionary. Wait for a while guys.

Answer (score -1):

This seems simple:

We need to distinguish between

a/one {[one] thousandth} = <sup>1</sup>/<sub>1000</sub>

two {[one] thousandth**s**} = <sup>2</sup>/<sub>1000</sub>

a/one {two thousandth} = <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2000</sub>

two {two thousandth**s**} = <sup>2</sup>/<sub>2000</sub>

Comment: It is more scholarly to address a challenged entry in a recognised resource with references supporting the counterclaim. If this is merely 'simple', migration should be the option.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth: Does anyone say "one one-fifths of a second"? - No. The Britannica entry is simply wrong. Note the OP's comment after checking 1/100ths: *The writer must have made a mistake.* Indeed they must - and you agree. My examples show the correct use and I think you will agree. I offer you Samuel Johnson: "You may scold a carpenter who has made you a bad table, though you cannot make a table. It is not your trade to make tables.”

Comment: Not my DV, by the way; I try to use balance.

Comment: @Greybeard - I think Edwin's point was that if it's so basic as not to need references, then it should go to ELL.  I've often wondered if there's a way to codify which things should be migrated and which not, and that seems like it might work.